# Where does Devi Bhagavatam say followers of Vaishnava Agamas go to hell?

Tags: agamas, devi-bhagavata-purana

In my question here [Why does Devi Bhagavatam say some Agamas as tamasic?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/33690/17821)

A user commented

> Devi Bhagavatam talks against many other Tantras too .. Like Vaishnava
>   Agama is also criticized as saying followers will go to dreaded hells
>   .. the branding of hot metal marks on body is censured.

Where does Devi Bhagavatam say this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is described in the fifteenth chapter of the eleventh canto of the Devi-Bhagavatam:

> O Muni! The S’iva-haters, the Visnu-haters, the 
>   Devî-haters are made to fall to this Kunda. Those who find fault with the Vedas, and blame 
>   the Sun, Ganes’a and tyrannise the Brâhmanas fall down to this hell. Those who blame their 
>   mothers, fathers, Gurus, elder brothers, the Smritis and Purânas and those as well **who take 
>   the Tapta Mudrâs (hot marks on their bodies)** and Tapta S’ûlas (i.e., those who being S’aivas 
>   act as they like) those who blame the religion (Dharma) go down to that hell. (**Devi-Bhagavatam 11.15.39-40**)

Comment: i guess the hot marks are like practice for what we're gonna face in hell.

Comment: That chapter emphasizes on Gayatri devi worship and censures almost all the sects and followers of many tantra sects and not only Vaishnavas. If that is true, Hell is going to be overcrowded with Kaula practitioners and Vaishnavas. 

Comment: @Sarvabhouma True lol. And welcome back!

Comment: Related: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/22801/what-scriptures-talk-against-tapta-mudrankana-practice

Comment: Devi Bhagavata Purana is one of the Puranas with prominent quality of tamas (ignorance) in them. And such tamasic texts are of very low quality of Vedic knowledge in them and not of much authority either because they often contradict Sruti, Smriti, Vedanta and sattvic texts. Acaryas (teachers) who were Vedantists rejected those low quality tamasic texts as unreliable source of Vedic knowledge. As a matter of fact acaryas sometimes has quoted the verses from those tamasic texts, but only if those verses are in line with authority, namely Sruti, Smriti, Vedanta, and sattvic Puranas.

Comment: @ram It's the other way. When you take those marks on your arms, you will not get any chance to face hell or the burnings there.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma, it was a joke. like if someone says 'working hard in office will cause to you lose job', and I say 'if i lose job, i have to work harder anyways, so i'm getting practice now'